# Recommendation for 3D-Resin

Tags: resin, material

I am looking for a resin to use with my Phrozen Sonic Mini 4K.

I am trying to print useable plastic connector shells for an industrial use-case.

**My requirements are:**

- Layer heights of approx. 50 µm or smaller possible in a reliable way
- Feature resolution is comparable to standard resins
- Minimal material wall-thickness of 0.15 mm in a reliable way
- Resistant to solvents commonly used in industrial environments

  Used for cleaning and so on, e.g. brake-cleaner.
- Somewhat comparable mechanical properties compared to PBT plastic [datasheet](https://www.matweb.com/search/DataSheet.aspx?MatGUID=781bd0e9d0854fd5a919866c39ea3065&ckck=1)
- Temperature range of -20 to 85 °C without major losses in mechanical properties
- Is dimensionally long-term stable

Price and vendor are, as long as reasonable, not an issue.

Comment: This seems like a shopping question, or recommendation, which aren't allowed on Stack Exchange, unfortunately. Maybe try to re-formulate the question so that it isn't a question that will attract opinion based answers.

Answer (score 1):

Your question contains mostly two important things,
1° Solvent resistance: Brake cleaner is mostly Acetone (90% and aroma compounds 10% in my experience)
You need a resin that resists Acetone then.
There are not a lot according to the tests by [Formlabs](https://support.formlabs.com/s/article/Solvent-Compatibility?language=en_US).

| Solvent | Grey Pro Resin V1 (FLPRGR01) | High Temp Resin V2 (FLHTAM02) | Rigid 4000 Resin (FLRGWH01) | Rigid 10K Resin (FLRG1001) | Tough Resin V5 (FlTOTL05) | Tough 1500 Resin V1 (FLTO1501) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Acetic acid (5%) | 0.8 | <1.0 | 0.8 | <0.1 | 2.8 | 0.8 |
| Acetone | 10.8 | <0.1 | 3.3 | <0.1 | sample cracked | 19.1 |

We can see that there are not a lot of resins that resist this solvent. Only one seems suitable: "Resin (FLRGWH01)  Rigid 10K Resin (FLRG1001)"

2° long-lasting mechanical stress :
the phenomenon is called "to creep" : (slowly deform) under constant pressure. Exerted by the bolts or clamping on the parts for example.
Please be careful as most of the resins can be prone to failure due to continuous use.

As the [Voron Materials Selection](https://docs.vorondesign.com/materials.html) explains.

> While on paper resin printed parts could work for heat resistance depending on the resin type, resin parts typically continue to shrink over time putting them outside of dimensional tolerances. Resin prints also typically exhibit long term creeping under bolt pressure and have a tendency to catastrophically fail after just a few months of use.

Maybe you can try this one out from the seller eSUN?
It has good mechanical properties. [Hard-Tough Resin](https://www.esun3d.com/hard-tough-resin-product/)

The brand is good but I don't think the solvent resistance is acceptable for you, but in the end, you should try it out and tell us here as this is an interesting topic to all of us here!
But frankly, as you can read on the links I posted... Resin is probably not a solution for you.

Comment: I changed the answer.